# how to restart scripts automatic

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the best way if you have a big script with a large process and you get an Error, then how to tell the script, wait 1min and begin again from top.

It's written in asp.net, c#.

Example

```
protected void doAll() {

FirstFunction();
// If I get in this function an error it should stop wait 1min. and start doAll() again.

NextFunction();

// END 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try** the code that may cause an error inside `FirstFunction()`. **Catch** the resulting error, **sleep** for a minute and call `doAll()`. I am not sure how it is done in ASP.NET/C#.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you are saying. Do you *really* want the user to wait 1, 2, 3 or even more minutes for a web page to download and render on their screen?

I strongly suggest you think about some other way of handling errors in this routine. Perhaps if you explained to us why you want to wait 1 minute, we might be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: It's a parse service which have to run each night. and if I get a bad response from server or anything like that it should wait 5mins and try again.

Comment: In that case, you should move it into a separate project, e.g. a Windows service or a command line app run by the Windows scheduler. ASP.NET web apps are meant for constructing and serving up web pages; they should not run code at arbitrary intervals, only when pages are requested by the user.

Comment: Later I have to run this aspx page with the windows scheduler thats right (or not possbile?). But I have to do this error checks as well..I think the scheduler just know when to start the script. I can't say stop scheduler and start if an error.

Comment: You don't need to. Your scheduled code would include an error handler that would re-try the parsing as many times as necessary.